# Movie about a monster attack shot on a video camera

Tags: identify-this-movie

I want to rewatch a nice movie that I've seen I think 6 years ago. So... let me describe it:

- First things first, from what I remembered was realeased around 2009. Can even be 2007, I do not know, 'cause I had it on my old computer and changed it, so the movie was gone.
- From what I know, it's that kind of "pov" movie recorded from a camera (bottom of the view was like *REC*).
- Here is the story that I remebered: Nice party at night at balcony, the main character with the camera went down with a friend to buy from the supermarket something, and then a building crashed, people were afraid, madness outside etc., and monster/godzilla/alien came from the distance, people ran, the main character was still in that street (I think New York was the city, cuz there were blocks left and right, skyscraper you know...)  So military came, they were attacked by baby monsters/small creatures... our guy and some friends went in the metro... they escaped the metro... went to a highway tunnel... and our guy died in a PARK.
- What's important to this park, is that from what I remembered is the movie cover (like a book cover - from what I remebered when I googled it 6 years ago), the cover shows a bridge, a park bridge - small river under it, you know, and from what I remebered the big creature in the background.

Comment: Aside from this question, a google search for "Movie about a monster attack shot on a video camera" brings back the IMDB page for cloverfield as the tip result.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You're describing the plot of [Cloverfield](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1060277/combined) from 2008.

> Cloverfield follows five New Yorkers from the perspective of a hand-held video camera. The movie is exactly the length of a DV Tape and a sub-plot is established by showing bits and pieces of video previously recorded on the tape that is being recorded over. The movie starts as a monster of unknown origin destroys a building. As they go to investigate, parts of the building and the head of the Statue of Liberty come raining down. The movie follows their adventure trying to escape and save a friend, a love interest of the main character.

Every single plot detail you mentioned is there. Here's the trailer:

Comment: I knew it from the title! Anyway after I watched it I had headache thats why I remember the movie...