# Horror/sci-fi alien attack found-footage movie

Tags: identify-this-movie, horror, science-fiction

I faintly remember this "found-footage"-esque movie of, I believe, 4 teens/young adults recording an alien attack on what is probably New York or another American city.

At some point they were in a dark underground tube, so the camera-guy turned on night-vision, and sees they are being chased by these huge spider-looking things.

I believe 2 of the 4 main characters die at two separate points in the movie.

In the ending the two remaining characters sat in the morning light, possibly dying.

- The movie was in english
- It was probably 10 years ago or so
- The camera man was one of the four main characters and I believe he dies at some point, leaving one of the others to pick up the camera
- The military was very much present, attempting to evacuate people and shooting the alien 'mothership' with tanks
- The 'mothership' was several stories or even buildings tall (maybe 50 meters), but its minions were probably only the size of large dogs (maybe 50-75 cm)

These are the details I most distinctly remember.

Comment: Probably too close to [this](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/44884/movie-about-a-monster-attack-shot-on-a-video-camera/) duplicate.

Comment: Sounds kinda like Skyline or Battle Los Angels or even possibly The Darkest Hour.  None of those *quite* fit though.

Comment: @Walt Since we are both referring to the same movie, obviously it could seem like a dublicate question, I just didn't happen to stumble upon his question when I searched for possible answers before posting my own. However, by reading through his question, I was not convinced he and I was looking for the same movie, as he was asking about more meta-esk stuff (the cover of the movie, release year etc.). My question also bring up two specific scenes, whereas his question bring up other scenes.

Comment: Sure, that's why I didn't mark it yet as such, I'm not that sure. But there are some similarities in the Qs. But of course you're not obligated to sift through all of our ID's, there are literally thousands of them.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is [**Cloverfield**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1060277/) (2008) and the smaller creatures you are referring to are called **Parasites**

> The monster was covered in 2,000 Parasites that are **roughly the same weight and height as a dog**. They have 10 legs consisting of six spider-like, double jointed limbs and 4 "pincers" on the top and back of its body. They have very large jaws, pale gray skin and multiple black eyes.
>
> <sup>[Wikia](http://cloverfield.wikia.com/wiki/Parasite)</sup>

Comment: This could definetly be it.. Once I saw the image of her bleeding from her eyes I just got swarmed with memories... Will check out the movie in more detail and give you the checkmark if this is indeed it.. Thanks for finding it!

Comment: That's definitely it. You might be interested to know that last year [10 Cloverfield Lane](https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/10_cloverfield_lane/) came out. It's not exactly a sequel but it is set in the same universe, though the way it was integrated is funny. It's a VERY different movie, not found footage, but it is excellent and I recommend it.